# Apply negative indexing to argument using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

```
test <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,1,0), B = c(1,1,5,6,2))
```

I would like to remove obsevation where A = 1 and B = 1

For example:

```
test <- test[-which(test$A == 1 & test$B == 1),]
```

How is  this done in dplyr?

```
 test <- filter(test, -(test$A == 1 & test$B == 1))

Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector.
```

Comment: `filter(test, !(A == 1 & B == 1))` ? or `filter(test, (A != 1 | B != 1))`? or `slice(test, -which(test$A == 1 & test$B == 1))`? or whatever

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(test, !(A == 1 & B == 1))
```

or

```
filter(test, (A != 1 | B != 1))
```

or

```
slice(test, -which(test$A == 1 & test$B == 1))
```

Comment: The `slice` alternative shown only works if there is at least one row satisfying the condition.

Comment: The `-which(.)` construction is well known to be risky. (My downvote for offering an answer that was someone else's comment and not providing any additional commentary or need correction.)